# At what elevation do 50% or higher percentages of mountaineers report symptoms of altitude sickness?

Tags: climbing, mountaineering, high-altitude

I've read somewhere that above 2500 meters (8,202 ft) 20% of climbers report having had altitude sickness. IIRC they also wrote that 40% of climbers report altitude sickness above 3500 meters (11,500 ft) though I'm unsure about the latter value. I wonder at what altitude the percentage approaches 50% and more. Preferrably in mid-latitude mountains (such as the Alps, the New Zealand Southern Alps, the Cascade range, northern Colorado or the Caucasus) because at the mid-latitudes the atmospheric pressure at an elevation should be about the same as at the pressure altitude on an aircraft's altimeter. Answer may include values from high altitude chambers.

Comment: I don't think there's a single number, as age, gender, physical condition, home elevation, rate of ascension and a lot of other factors come into play. [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3678789/) covers the Alps and Colorado as well as Nepal.

Comment: It can be unclear what a person means by "altitude sickness".  That is, what I commonly experience on Day 1 and think of as merely an annoying headache and a feeling of blahness, which clears up overnight or in at most a day, may be somebody else's definition of altitude sickness.   Is this technically altitude sickness?  Perhaps, but I don't think it is helpful to lump together minor, transitory symptoms with the sort of symptoms that demand a quick retreat to a lower elevation.  Calling the latter "acute altitude sickness" is helpful, but  (continued)

Comment: (continued)  without more info on symptoms, "altitude sickness" by itself can mean almost anything.

Comment: It isn't useful to compare mountaineering with the pressure in an aircraft, where the passengers are inactive, and the crew are accustomed to the reduced pressure.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm talking about the outside pressure, not a pressurized cabin. A plane's altimeter set to 29.92 inHg is using the International Standard Atmosphere for determining the pressure altitude it is at, or flight level. E.g. when the altimeter shows 12950 ft, it actually means "the outside pressure is 9 psi", that's approximately the pressure at 12950 ft above mid-latitudes. At the equator however, the pressure would be higher, and therefore the pressure altitude lower at the same absolute altitude, because the atmosphere is more expanded at the equator. That's why I asked like this.

Comment: I live near 6000 feet. The only time in my life I definitely have had mild altitude sickness was when I drove to a campground at around 8000 feet. That night I had had a wicked headache and mild nausea. Before and after I've been much higher, even under similar conditions (short drive to a campground - just was up over 11,000 feet). The difference in that one time? I'd spent about two weeks at sea level, then returned home for a week before going camping. So even for one person, how and when altitude symptoms start depends on many variables.

Comment: https://jphysiolanthropol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s40101-023-00322-7 (Ebihara et al.
Journal of Physiological Anthropology (2023) 42:6
https://doi.org/10.1186/s40101-023-00322-7) has a study of 11 ("This study included 11 healthy subjects who climbed
mountains of > 2000 m once or twice per year.") folks, 4 of whom experienced a level of AMS upon an 8 hour climb and overnight stay on Mt Fuji. Looks like a variety of good references.

Comment: @Johannes As the one answer already says, this isn't preciscely defined. Mostly because AMS isn't precicely defined. Are you talking about LLS or CAS? And which score? And so on. Also the starting symptoms like headaches and nausea are very fluent. Medication, fitness level, exercise and acclimatization can drastically change the outcome. Especially if you mix things like walking up a mountain, planes at altitude and hypoxic chambers together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not definable to the level of precision you seem to be imagining, but probably somewhere around 16,000' (~4,900 meters). It depends on what criteria you use. For some references, see the introductory section of this paper: Dallimore, J., & Rowbotham, E. C. (2009). Incidence of Acute Mountain Sickness in Adolescents. Wilderness & Environmental Medicine, 20(3), 221–224. doi:10.1580/07-weme-or-119r3.1  https://sci-hub.se/10.1580/07-WEME-OR-119R3.1

There is a background rate of something like 10%, which is just because people often feel bad while they're in the mountains because of factors like lack of sleep, caffeine withdrawal, and so on: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22441083/